# A Counting Proof

Tags: combinatorics

For fixed positive integers $m$ and $n$, let
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k\binom{m}{k}(m-k)^n.$$Show that $S = 0$ if $n < m$ and $S = n!$ if $n = m$.

**I have asked this question before: [Proof Involving Sigmas](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1886100/proof-involving-sigmas),  but have not received any answer that I could relate to.**  I know that I have to use PIE(principle of inclusion and exclusion) and a counting argument.  Here's my work so far:

There are $m$ people, $\binom{m}{k}$ represents all the ways to pick $k$ people out of $m$ people.  $(m-k)^n$ represents all the ways of giving the people that weren't chosen $n$ distinguishable objects.  What I don't get is how to apply PIE, why the signs are alternating, and how does $S = 0$ if $n < m$ and $S = n!$ if $n = m$.  Could anyone offer an answer by the counting argument I started?  Thanks!

Comment: You should have added this to the earlier question or left me a comment under my answer rather than repeating the question. I’ll expand my answer there a bit, but I’ll have to think a little about just how to do it most usefully. Did you look at the two earlier answers to which I linked?

Comment: Notice:

$$\text{S}=\sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^k\binom{m}{k}(m-k)^n=m!\mathcal{S}_{n}^{(m)}$$

Where $\mathcal{S}_{n}^{(m)}$ is the Stirling number of the second kind.


http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheSecondKind.html

Comment: In any case, posting the same question again is inappropriate.