# Partition Proof Using One-to-One Correspondences

Tags: integer-partitions

Let $g(n,k)$ be the number of partitions of $n$ into exactly $k$ parts, in which no part is a $1$. Show that
$$g(n,k) = g(n-2,k-1) + g(n-k,k).$$

I know that the solution involves a one-to-one correspondence.  I tried listing a few examples, but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Let $P(n,k)$ be the set of partitions of $n$ into exactly $k$ parts, none of which is a $1$. We can split $P(n,k)$ into two subsets:

- Let $P_0(n,k)$ be the set of partitions in $P(n,k)$ that do not have a part that is a $2$. In other words, $P_0(n,k)$ is the set of partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts, all of which are at least $3$.
- Let $P_1(n,k)$ be the set of partitions in $P(n,k)$ that *do* have a $2$ part.

Clearly $P_0(n,k)$ and $P_1(n,k)$ are disjoint, and $P_0(n,k)\cup P_1(n,k)=P(n,k)$, so

$$g(n,k)=|P_0(n,k)|+|P_1(n,k)|\;.$$

Now try to match up the cardinalities $|P_0(n,k)|$ and $|P_1(n,k)|$ with the two terms on the righthand side of the recurrence that you’re trying to prove.

Comment: How does $P_0(n,k)$ and $P_1(n,k)$ relate to $g(n-2,k-1)$ and $g(n-k,k)$?

Comment: @MathMuse: $g(n-2,k-1)$ is the cardinality of one of those two sets, and $g(n-k,k)$ is the cardinality of the other. Here’s an additional hint: if you take a partition in $P_0(n,k)$ and subtract $1$ from each part, you get a partition in $P(n-k,k)$.

Comment: Wait, how is that correct?  Could you explain it to me?  And how does $P_1(n,k)$ have the same amount as $P(n-1,k-1)$?

Comment: @MathMuse: $P_1(n,k)$ is the same size as $P(n-\color{red}{2},k-1)$: if a partition is in $P_1(n,k)$, it has a $2$ part, and when you throw away that $2$ part, what’s left is a partition of $n-2$ into $k-1$ parts, none of which is a $1$.

Comment: Okay, I get it.  But what about $P_0(n,k)$ and $P(n-k,k)$?  How does "if you take a partition in $P_0(n,k)$ and subtract 1 from each part, you get a partition in $P(n−k,k)$" work?

Comment: @MathMuse: Have you been introduced to [Ferrers diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Ferrers_diagram) of partitions?

Comment: No.  Could that proof be complete without Ferrers diagrams?

Comment: @MathMuse: Sure; the diagrams just make it very easy to understand what’s going on. Consider the partition $5+5+4+3$ of $17$; it’s in $P_0(17,4)$. If you subtract $1$ from each part, you get $4+4+3+2$, which is in $P(17-4,4)=P(13,4)$. Can you see why something like this will always happen? The original partition of $17$ has no $1$ parts, so subtracting $1$ from each part still leaves $4$ parts, and it also has no $2$ parts, so the reduced partition has no $1$ parts.

Comment: Okay, I see it now!  Thanks for responding to my ongoing questions and taking the time to explain the answers!  Answer accepted and +1!

Comment: @MathMuse: You’re welcome!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44075/discussion-between-math-muse-and-brian-m-scott).

Comment: @MathMuse: I may have to leave before too long, but I’m there now.