# Proving Cayley s formula from a sum

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I need to prove

$\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}i^{n-2}(-1)^{n-i+1}=0$

The above can be written as

$\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{i}i^{n-2}(-1)^{n-i+1}\right)-n^{n-2}=0$

So I need to prove that

$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{i}i^{n-2}(-1)^{n-i+1}=n^{n-2}$

Which is Cayley's formula

Comment: See [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a reference on how to type with MathJax and $\LaTeX$ here.

Comment: Please check that I typeset your problem correctly and that it shows what you intended.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help I am new here as you can see haha. I wanted (-1)^n-i+1 I must typed wrongly at first its +1 not -1 at the power of (-1)

Comment: That won't make a difference as $(-1)^{k-1}=(-1)^{k-1}\cdot (-1)^2 = (-1)^{k+1}$ since $(-1)^2 = 1$

Comment: Any help for the proof?

Comment: I suspect it’s still true if you replace $n-2$ in the exponents with general $m$. You might be able to do an induction with the strengthened hypothesis.

Comment: Yeah, this is the same as doing $n$ finite differences on a polynomial of degree $n-2$, so it’s 0.

Comment: You may find [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1875714/simplifying-sum-r-0n-n-chooserrk-1r/1875784#1875784) useful: with $k=n-2$ it’s your question (up to a possible factor of $-1$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much more straightforward combinatorial proof:

$n^{n-2}$ counts the number of functions $[n-2]\to [n]$

On the other hand, if we try to count the number of functions $[n-2]\to [n]$ via inclusion-exclusion that at least one number from $[n]$ does not appear in the image... that is letting $A_k$ count the functions $f$ such that $k\notin\operatorname{Image}(f)$, we try to count $|A_1\cup A_2\cup\dots\cup A_n|$ and break apart via inclusion-exclusion.

For $1\leq n-i$ elements guaranteed not in the image, we pick which those are in $\binom{n}{n-i}=\binom{n}{i}$ ways.  For each element of the domain, we pick which of the $n-(n-i)=i$ elements in the available range of not already disqualified elements of the codomain they map to which can be done in $i^{n-2}$ ways.  The $(-1)^{n-i+1}$ term appears as a result of inclusion-exclusion.  Altogether then we find there are $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{i}i^{n-2}(-1)^{n-i+1}$ such functions.

We of course know that since $n-2<n$ there is *always* going to be at least one element of $[n]$ not in the image of every function $f$ from $[n-2]\to [n]$ so these must be equal.

---

Proof via calculus:

$(x+1)^n=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}x^i$

Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$ to get

$n(x+1)^{n-1} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}ix^{i-1}$

Multiply both sides by $x$ to get

$nx(x+1)^{n-1}=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}ix^i$

Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$ again to get

$n(nx+1)(x+1)^{n-2} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}i^2x^{i-1}$

Repeat this process so that the total number of derivatives performed was $n-2$ and we end with $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}i^{n-2}x^{i-1}$ on the right.  On the left, we end with some ugly expression, but that expression will necessarily have a factor of $(x+1)$ in it.  This can be seen by the product rule of differentiation, that $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$, at each step of the process letting $g(x)$ refer to the $(x+1)^{n-k}$ factor noting that the derivative of $(x+1)^{n-k}$ is $(n-k)(x+1)^{n-k-1}$.

> The exact expression after $k>0$ steps can be shown to be $n\frac{k-1}{~}(nx+k-1)(x+1)^{n-k}=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}i^kx^i$ where $a\frac{b}{~}$ is notation for [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)

Now, plugging in $-1$ for $x$, the expression on the right is equal to your original expression.  The expression on the left, having a factor of $(1+x)$ thus has a factor of $(1+(-1))$ and is thus equal to zero.

Indeed, as noted in the comments, by performing only $k$ steps in this process, this shows that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}i^k(-1)^i=0$ for any $0\leq k\leq n-2$.

Comment: Interesting solution. I haven't considered to solve it via calculus because the guidance to the solution I have been given is going through the binomial theorem and combinatorics. Thanks for this different point of view.

Comment: @DontWorry I found a much cleaner combinatorial explanation which I added at the top.

Answer (score 0):

We get for the intial sum

$$\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} q^{n-2} (-1)^{n-q+1}
= (n-2)! [z^{n-2}] \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} \exp(qz) (-1)^{n-q+1}
\\ = - (n-2)! [z^{n-2}] (\exp(z)-1)^n.$$

Now since $\exp(z)-1 = z + \cdots$ we have $(\exp(z)-1)^n = z^n + \cdots$ and $[z^{n-2}] (z^n + \cdots) = 0$ as claimed.